# adding new mySQL table row with PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I got a little form:

```
<form id="plannerform" action="save.php" method="post">
    <input id="plannername" placeholder=" " type="text" autocomplete="off" name="plannername">
    <input id="plannersubmit" type="submit" value="eintragen">
</form>
```

As you can see there is the `action="save.php"` and `method="post"` on the text-input there is `name="plannername"`.

And thats my php:

```
$con = mysql_connect("myHost","myUser","myPW");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("myDB", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO anmeldungen (FR_PM)
VALUES ('$_POST[plannername]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";
```

The `FR_PM` is one column of my table. But when I press submit, not even a new row gets created. Nothing happens. 
But when I call my php with "mywebsite.com/save.php" it adds a new row in my table (with no value at "FR_PM", what's pretty obvious)

What do I do wrong?

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 3):

one of the things that you need to learn if you are a beginner, you should try by all means to stay away from using `mysql_*` function this is depreciated and its no longer supported in php. instead use `mysqli_*` with prepared statements, or use PDO prepared statements.

prepared statments make you code looks clean and its easy to debug.

this is you example with prepared statements.

```
<form id="plannerform" action="save.php" method="post">
    <input id="plannername" placeholder=" " type="text" autocomplete="off" name="plannername">
    <input id="plannersubmit" type="submit" value="eintragen" name="submit">
 </form>
```

s**ave.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "";
$dbname     = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['plannername'])) {

        die("Enter plannername");
    } else {
        // prepare and bind
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO anmeldungen (FR_PM) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['plannername']);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {

            echo "New records created successfully";

        } else {

            echo "Could not insert record";
        }

        $stmt->close();

    }
}
?>
```

The reason I used prepared statements :

- Prepared statements reduces parsing time as the preparation on the
  query is done only once (although the statement is executed multiple
  times)
- Bound parameters minimize bandwidth to the server as you need send
  only the parameters each time, and not the whole query
- Prepared statements are very useful against SQL injections, because
  parameter values, which are transmitted later using a different
  protocol, need not be correctly escaped. If the original statement
  template is not derived from external input, SQL injection cannot
  occur.

> But when I call my php with "mywebsite.com/save.php" it adds a new row
>   in my table (with no value at "FR_PM", what's pretty obvious)
>
> What do I do wrong?

Well do prevent that from happening you need to check if the form was submitted before you can actual process any thing.

> **Note: If we want to insert any data from external sources (like user input from a form ), it is very important that the data is sanitized
>   and validated. always treat input from a form as if its from a very
>   dangerous hacker**

Comment: I am using your code, but still. nothing is happening when I submit.

Comment: did you update your form and add the name attribute to your button? this code should work. @TobiasGlaus

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Ah, half of the problem solved. But now something strange happens. Can you come into this chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42482/web-developers I post an image there

Answer (score 0):

change your insert query:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO anmeldungen (FR_PM) VALUES ('".$_POST["plannername"]."')";
```

Or

```
$plannername = $_POST["plannername"];
$sql="INSERT INTO anmeldungen (FR_PM) VALUES ('".$plannername."')";
```

Comment: still. nothing happens when I submit.

Comment: You can also put braces around the array variable : `"...VALUES ('{$_POST['plannername']}')";`

Comment: @TobiasGlaus just see whether you are getting the value of `$_POST["plannername"]` or not?

Comment: @Punit.. I don't get anything in the console. Whereelse could I get errors?

Comment: @PathikVejani How can I check that?

Comment: @TobiasGlaus just do echo $_POST["plannername"]; exit;

Comment: error log, if you using apache, its in a folder logs, error.log

Comment: @PathikVejani No this is just giving me a blank page when I call it on "mypage.com/save.php"

Comment: @TobiasGlaus then value is not going to posted on the submit

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I am working on a webserver. There is a .logs folder with a php_error.log but it's blank

Comment: @PathikVejani How can I get it posted?

Comment: @TobiasGlaus , let us know your folder structure

Comment: at the top of **save.php** add this  `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: How can I move this to chat.stackoverflow.com? So I can upload an image of it

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile `Notice: Undefined index: plannername in /.../.../save.php on line 3`

Comment: @TobiasGlaus check my answer above, it does deal with that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Also, use `"name"=` and not `"id"=` in the HTML form.
This is usually misleading when working with forms and HTTP POST method.

Comment: Ook good, because I have been stuck in the same problem, too.

Answer (score -1):

you may try

```
$value = $_POST['plannername'];

$sql="INSERT INTO anmeldungen (FR_PM) VALUES ('{$value}')";
```